# How equation 6 has been solved to get equation 7? Can someone help me solving it with explanation?.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading one research paper, where they have solved the equation 6, and getting the answer as expressed in equation 7 . I can't understand how exactly they have solved it.
$$
\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = \alpha C u + \frac{Q}{PBL} − \alpha C(t)
\tag{6}
$$
Assuming equilibrium, we can solve the differential eq 6. and obtain the following solution:
$$
C = Cu + \frac{Q}{\alpha PBL} + C_1 e^{−\alpha t}\tag{7}
$$
Thank you.

Comment: It may be helpful to include the paper as there may be an explanation in the text that could help answerers help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a separable equation, that can be written as
$$
\frac{dC}{C - Cu-Q/\alpha PBL} = -\alpha dt
$$
Integrating both sides, you have
$$
\ln |C-Cu - Q/\alpha PBL| = C_0-\alpha t, 
$$
or
$$
C = Cu + \frac{Q}{\alpha PBL} C_1 e^{-\alpha t}.
$$